# What to do to a gnawing laptop

Tags: 12.04, sound, maintenance

My laptop model no. is  HP-630 .The battery of my laptop is not working at all. Even if I fully charge it, after 30-45 minutes  a message gets displayed that the battery has been exhausted.

The specifications of my laptop are

- 2.14 GHz Processor ,500 GB Hard Disk,2 GB RAM,Intel Core I-3 Processor; Ubuntu 12.04 installed in it running for 4 years.

The laptop is giving a gnawing sound when running and the laptop is getting very hot.I don't know why?

**Question 1**:Is it wise to exchange my laptop and go for a new one or is it okay to buy a new battery instead? I am in a fix.

**Question 2**:I would be happy if someone could give me some advice and even give some tips on   what configurations should a new laptop contain.I only use it for running C-programs and searching questions.

Do tell me if this question is suitable for this site or not?If not where should I ask it?

Comment: Most laptops will run just fine on AC with the battery removed. Try that and see if the heat or sound are related to a defective battery. When you find the the overheating is due to a bad battery, you can buy a new one pretty cheap. When the noise is still there, you can continue to investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't have to buy a new laptop if you will use it only for writing C programs and searching.

> I would suggest buying a new battery and if it doesn't work for you then get it checked from a service center.Since 4 years is a lot of time it may happen that your battery may be damaged and it isn't working to it's full capacity.

If the new battery thing doesn't work come again and ask about the specifications.

> P.S. As you asked, this question is not suitable for this site because it's a site related to Ubuntu specific problems.But since you are a Ubuntu user the Ubuntu community will always be there to help you.

Answer (score 0):

First, only ask one question per Question. It makes it easier for other people to search your question and its answer.

Second, replacing the battery will cost much less than replacing the laptop, so that's what I recommend as a first step.